# postgresql in lxc container doesn't start after reboot

Tags: debian, postgresql, lxc

Debian stable (Jessie)

I have few containers - in one container there is postgresql. I want to start it first (I hope that my config does it).

After reboot all containers starts, but i can't log in few of them (ssh doesn't starts, console neither). So I have to lxc-stop -n base; lxc-start -n base -d.

After that i can log in, but postgresql is stopped. But log says, that it is stopped by reboot, not by lxc-stop (or lxc-stop doesn't affect logs)

How to find why it isn't started correctly after reboot

I would like to show log, but it is in polish (how to change it into english)?

```
2016-03-06 09:43:53 CET [825-1] postgres@postgres KATASTROFALNY:  system bazy danych uruchamia się
2016-03-06 09:43:54 CET [831-1] postgres@postgres KATASTROFALNY:  system bazy danych uruchamia się
2016-03-06 09:43:54 CET [837-1] postgres@postgres KATASTROFALNY:  system bazy danych uruchamia się
2016-03-06 09:43:54 CET [595-1] DZIENNIK:  odebrano żądanie inteligentnego zamknięcia
2016-03-06 09:44:15 CET [737-2] DZIENNIK:  system bazy danych nie został poprawnie zamknięty; trwa automatyczne odzyskiwanie
2016-03-06 09:44:17 CET [737-3] DZIENNIK:  record with zero length at 0/A1B44AB8
2016-03-06 09:44:17 CET [737-4] DZIENNIK:  ponowienie nie jest wymagane
2016-03-06 09:44:18 CET [737-5] DZIENNIK:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2016-03-06 09:44:18 CET [951-1] DZIENNIK:  zamykanie 
2016-03-06 09:44:19 CET [951-2] DZIENNIK:  system bazy danych jest zamknięty
```

lxcconfig:

```
#Autostart
lxc.start.auto = 1
lxc.start.delay = 0
lxc.start.order = 1000
lxc.group = onboot


lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/base/rootfs
lxc.tty = 4
lxc.pts = 1024
lxc.arch = amd64
lxc.utsname = base
lxc.cap.drop = sys_module mac_admin mac_override sys_time
lxc.autodev = 1
lxc.kmsg = 0
```

(...)